# How do I get Tcl's exec to run a command whose arguments have quoted strings with spaces?

Tags: shell, tcl, exec, eval, quoting

I want to use `pgrep` to find the pid of a process from its command-line. In the shell, this is done as so:

```
pgrep -u andrew -fx 'some_binary -c some_config.cfg'
```

But when I try this from Tcl, like this:

```
exec pgrep -u $user -fx $cmdLine
```

I get:

> pgrep: invalid option -- 'c'

Which makes sense, because it's seeing this:

```
pgrep -u andrew -fx some_binary -c some_config.cfg
```

But it's the same when I add single quotes:

```
exec pgrep -u $user -fx '$cmdLine'
```

And that also makes sense, because single quotes aren't special to Tcl. I think it's consider `'some_binary` an argument, then the `-c`, then the `some_config.cfg'`.

I've also tried:

```
exec pgrep -u $user -fx {$cmdLine}
```

and

```
set cmd "pgrep -u $user -fx '$cmdLine'"
eval exec $cmd
```

to no avail.

From my reading it seems the `{*}` feature in Tcl 8.5+ might help, but my company infrastructure runs Tcl 8.0.5.

Comment: `exec` should pass its arguments to the invoked command as is (i.e. no concatenation and re-splitting must take place). Do you execute `exec` via `eval`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is partially that `'` means nothing at all to Tcl, and partially that you're losing control of where the word boundaries are.

---

Firstly, double check that this actually works:

```
exec pgrep -u $user -fx "some_binary -c some_config.cfg"
```

or perhaps this (Tcl uses `{`…`}` like Unix shells use single quotes but with the added benefit of being nestable; that's what braces *really* do in Tcl):

```
exec pgrep -u $user -fx {some_binary -c some_config.cfg}
```

What ought to work is this:

```
set cmdLine "some_binary -c some_config.cfg"
exec pgrep -u $user -fx $cmdLine
```

where you have set `cmdLine` to *exactly* the characters that you want to have in it (check by printing out if you're unsure; what matters is the value in the variable, not the quoted version that you write in your script). I'll use the `set cmdLine "…"` form below, but really use whatever you need for things to work.

Now, if you are going to be passing this past `eval`, then you should use `list` to add in the extra quotes that you need to make things safe:

```
set cmdLine "some_binary -c some_config.cfg"
set cmd [list pgrep -u $user -fx $cmdLine]
eval exec $cmd
```

The `list` command produces lists, but it uses a *canonical form* that is also a script fragment that is ***guaranteed*** to lack “surprise” substitutions or word boundaries.

---

If you were on a more recent version of Tcl (specifically 8.5 or later), you'd be able to use expansion. That's designed to *specifically* work very well with `list`, and gets rid of the need to use `eval` in about 99% of all cases. That'd change the:

```
eval exec $cmd
```

into:

```
exec {*}$cmd
```

The semantics are a bit different *except* when `cmd` is holding a canonical list, when they actually run the same operation. (The differences come when you deal with non-canonical lists, where `eval` would do all sorts of things — imagine the havoc with `set cmd {ab [exit] cd}`, which is a valid but non-canonical list — whereas expansion just forces things to be a list and uses the words in the list without further interpretation.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on a old version, you have to make sure that what `eval` sees will be converted to a properly quoted Tcl string.

Single quotes do nothing.  They are not used by `exec`, nor are they passed on.  `exec` utilizes the underlying `exec(3)` system call, and no argument interpretation will take place unless you purposely use something like: `/bin/sh -c "some-cmd some-arg"` where the shell is invoked and will reinterpret the command line.

What you have to do is construct a string that `eval` will interpret as a quoted Tcl string.  You can use "{part1 part2}" or "\"part1 part2\"" for these constructs.

First, a little test script to verify that the arguments are being passed correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@"; do
  echo $i
done
```

Then the Tcl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
exec ./t.sh -u andrew -fx "some_binary -c some_config.cfg" >@ stdout
eval exec ./t.sh -u andrew -fx "{some_binary -c some_config.cfg}" \
     >@ stdout
eval exec ./t.sh -u andrew -fx "\"some_binary -c some_config.cfg\"" \
     >@ stdout
# the list will be converted to a string that is already properly
# quoted for interpretation by eval.
set cmd [list ./t.sh -u andrew -fx "some_binary -c some_config.cfg"]
eval exec $cmd >@ stdout
```